# System.OutOfMemoryException even though we have lots of RAM

Tags: c#, sql, windows-7

I'm running SQL Server 2012 Developer edition with windows 7 PRO and 64 gb of RAM.

We get the System.OutOfMemoryException was thrown when we do a lot of in memory requests.

Is there a quick fix to allow SQL to use more of the physical RAM?

Code:

```
// int count = MAX_BARS_IN_MEMORY / tf.timeperiod + 1;
                    hCommandBars.CommandText = String.Format(@"SELECT top " +     MAX_BARS_IN_MEMORY + " * FROM {0} WHERE {0}.timeperiod = " + tf.timeperiod + " ORDER BY     {0}.bartime desc", tableName);
                    barTimesAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(hCommandBars);
                    barTimesAdapter.Fill(dTimeset);
                    foreach (DataTable table in dTimeset.Tables)
                    {
                        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {

                            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                            {
                                InMemoryTable inMemorytable = new InMemoryTable();
                                inMemorytable.BarTime = Convert.ToDateTime((row["bartime"].ToString()));
                                inMemorytable.High = Convert.ToDouble(row["high"].ToString());
                                inMemorytable.Low = Convert.ToDouble(row["low"].ToString());
                                inMemorytable.Open = Convert.ToDouble(row["open"].ToString());
                                inMemorytable.Close = Convert.ToDouble(row["close"].ToString());
                                inMemorytable.C1 = Convert.ToDouble(row["c1"].ToString());
                                inMemorytable.C2 = Convert.ToDouble(row["c2"].ToString());
                                inMemorytable.SNR2 = false;
                                inMemorytable.Symbol = symbol.Key;//symbol name
                                inMemorytable.TimePeriod = Convert.ToInt32(row["timeperiod"].ToString());

                                _SessAndBarTableList.Add(inMemorytable);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dTimeset.AcceptChanges();
                    dTimeset.Clear();
                }





            hConnectionBars.Close();
            hConnectionBars.Dispose();
            hConnectionBars = null;
        //});
        }

         _SessAndBarTableList = _SessAndBarTableList.OrderBy(x => x.BarTime).ToList();
         _1MinuteTableList = _1MinuteTableList.OrderBy(x => x.BarTime).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: You are aware that the CLR has an object size limit.. ?

Comment: Please fix the OOME when "we do a lot of in memory requests"? Not easy with the amount of info/effort you put into your question.

Comment: Can you give us more info?

Comment: we do a look back "static string DATE_TO_LOOK_BACK_IN_MEMORY = "2012-12-16 00:00:00.000" and when we keep date close to present day, it works fine.  When we want to load a few months, we get the exception.  I know this is a low level explanation but it is all I know at present.

Comment: No, it runs as a 32-bit.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I'm not aware, is likely my problem?

Comment: Does SQL Server generate the message or does your application?

Comment: @ta.speot.is the app never reaches more than 1.5gb as far as I can tell so I haven't compiled it as a 64 bit app as of yet.  Is that the issue?

Comment: @ta.speot.is in debug mode, VS generates the error.  If I run without debugger, the app crashes.

Comment: 1.5GB looks close to the limit of what the .NET Framework will allow you to use in 32-bit process. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee815708.aspx *In a .NET Framework application, the common language runtime limits the total size of the managed heaps to slightly less than one-half of the maximum size of the private area portion of a process address space. For a 32-bit processes running on a 32-bit machine, 2 GB represents the upper limit of the private portion of the process address space.*

Comment: So if it runs as a 32bit process, having 64gigs of ram won't matter.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use an `SqlDataReader` rather than a `DataSet`. That would prevent you from getting all of the data from the server in one big chunk, which might solve the problem. However, if you're returning a lot of rows, you might still run into a problem adding items to the table.

How many rows are these big queries returning?